# What are the potential reasons for my problem with running multiprocessed Python script from elsewhere?

Tags: python, c#, multiprocessing

I have a Python script that uses multiprocessing, specifically `Pool().map()` from the package `multiprocessing`.

When I run the script locally on my machine, I remember to say `if __name__ == "__main__"` before running my code, and I run it by simply pressing `run` in my IDE.

It works, does everything I expect it to.

However, at work, we have this server (I believe it uses C#) which takes Python scripts and executes them. When I upload my script to this server, the multiprocessing part of the code fails.

Is is hard for me to tell what's going on (I do not have access to the server so I have limited info to work with, and really this problem is not my responsibility, so I am asking purely out of curiosity), however, it seems that the code does **not** throw an error, but rather it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop of some sort, creating and ending new sessions over and over. No work happens inside these sessions, they just begin and end.

Moreover, the code never actually enters the multiprocessed part of the code (i.e. the functions that I map to the `Pool`) , since if it did, it would fail (since for debugging, I threw a `raise Exception` as soon as the code enters the code that is meant to run parallel, just to check if it ever reaches it … but it never does).

Any clue what is going on, and how it is meant to be fixed?